# Quadratic Equation Calculator using Tkinter. Trouble Defining Variables

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on making a quadratic calculator with a GUI. I have both parts independently up and running, but now while trying to combine them I am running into an issue. Here is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math

def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get()

def search():
    print(a.get())
    print(b.get())
    print(c.get())
    return ''

#Window and Title
root = Tk()
root.title("Quadratic Calculator")
root.configure(background="black")
Label (root, text="Quadratic Calculator", bg="black", fg="grey", font="none 18 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)

a=StringVar()
b=StringVar()
c=StringVar()

#inputs
Label (root, text="Enter your A value!", bg="black", fg="grey", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(root, width=20, bg="white", textvariable=a)
textentry.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
Label (root, text="Enter your B value!", bg="black", fg="grey", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(root, width=20, bg="white", textvariable=b)
textentry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)
Label (root, text="Enter your c value!", bg="black", fg="grey", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=N)
textentry = Entry(root, width=20, bg="white", textvariable=c)
textentry.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)

#Answer
Label (root, text="Answer!", bg="black", fg="grey", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=N)
output = Text(root, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, bg="white")
output.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
d = (math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c)
if d < 0:
   print("There is no answer")
elif d == 0:
     x =(-b + (d))/ (2*a)
     print("There is one answer:",x)

else:
    x1 = ( -b + (math.sqrt(d)))/ (2*a)
    x2 = ( -b - (math.sqrt(d)))/ (2*a)
    print("There are two answers:", x1,"and" ,x2)

#Solve Button
Button(root, text="Solve", width=6, command=search) .grid(row=10, column=0,
sticky=N)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem I have been having is that the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are `float`s in my one program, but in this one for them to be gathered as inputs they must be strings. How do I make it so that in one part of my program they can be a string and in the other they can be a float. Or how do I make one fit for both. Don't be afraid to make critiques of anything else this is a learning experience for me. The exact error I get is `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'StringVar'`.

Comment: you probably want to use `a.get()` on the `StringVar a`, not `a` directly, that is `float(a.get())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two set of changes to get your calculator to start working.

Since `a`, `b`, and `c` need to contain `float` values, it would be slightly more convenient to make them of type `tkinter.DoubleVar` because that way you wouldn't need to retrieve and convert the string values each contains into `float` values everywhere else they were needed to be that type.

Note that because your program expects them to be something valid, mathematically, when it starts up, they'll also need to initialized with some values won't cause a error when they're used in the evaluating the statements based on the formula that solves the equation:

```
a = DoubleVar()
a.set(1.0)
b = DoubleVar()
b.set(0.0)
c = DoubleVar()
c.set(0.0)
```

To avoid the problem of needing both tkinter widgets for the GUI and `float` values for the computations, the simplest solution is probably just to retrieve and store the float values in temporary variables and use those as needed. In your code that all happens in the `#Answer` section. Note that this approach avoids changing the type of object (a tkinter widget) that the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are assigned to (unlike the code in your question).

```
# Get current values of DoubleVars.
a_val = a.get()
b_val = b.get()
c_val = c.get()

d = math.pow(b_val, 2) - 4*a_val*c_val
if d < 0:
    print("There is no answer")
elif d == 0:
    x = (-b_val + d) / (2*a_val)
    print("There is one answer:", x)
else:
    x1 = (-b_val + math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a_val)
    x2 = (-b_val - math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a_val)
    print("There are two answers:", x1, "and", x2)
```

Comment: Ludi: Glad it helped. Note in hindsight a better solution that would been resulted in code that was more readable would be to "reverse" the suggested changes and instead renamed the `a`, `b`, and `c` widgets to `a_var`, `b_var`, and `c_var` and then in the other part of your code do `a = a_var.get()`, `b = b_var.get()`, etc at the beginning. That way all the code following that which does the math wouldn't have needed to also be changed.